# Target is Only Updating Once

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

My main form has tabs (a TabControl) and my target control (a TextBox) is in the third tab. On the first tab, I have several TextBox controls where I enter data. My code parses the data entered and determines the maximum value, which it stores in a property that is bound to my target TextBox.

```
textBox_Offset_ODR_MaxDepth.DataBindings
                           .Add("Text", kernel.Targets, Targets.MaxDepthName);
```

When I run the program, I add data on my first tab, look at my third tab, and then see that the TextBox has been updated properly. It shows the maximum value correctly. So then I go back to my first tab, change the data, and then look at my third tab again. The value has not been updated.

I can see from other controls that use the source property in calculations that the source property has indeed been updated, but that update hasn't been pushed to the target TextBox.

How can I get the TextBox to always update when the source property changes?

I'll give my workaround as an answer to this with the hope that I'll help someone else, but it would be even better if someone could identify my problem and tell me what I'm doing wrong. I've been searching for several hours.

Comment: I think you meant to say "OnPropertyChanged", a method of the "INotifyPropertyChanged" interface. I do implement this method, which I guess is the reason that it gets updated the first time and then updated again with the Button I created. However, in forming this reply to your comment, I've found the real problem that I was having. I'll make a new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point I had (for some strange reason) commented out my declaration of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
class Targets// : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

My class implemented the interface, but that declaration at the top had been commented out. For some reason, this allows the target control to be updated only once. When I removed the commenting

```
class Targets : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

it ran fine and updated the target control appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I added a "Refresh" Button and gave it this code:

```
private void button_Offset_ODR_Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox_Offset_ODR_MaxDepth.DataBindings[0].ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.Never;
    textBox_Offset_ODR_MaxDepth.DataBindings[0].ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you seem like a real "shoot first, ask questions later" kind of guy.